# how to POST and insert array values into mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

i have html form, how can i insert into mysql table and also need to send e-mail this details, i know this is too difficult, can anyone give some idea and how to start.

```
<form id="validation" action="insert_export.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<table class="table table-bordered" style="width:95%;float:right;">
              <tr>
                <th><input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()"/></th>
                <th>S. No</th>
                <th>Item Code</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td>
                <td><span id='snum'>1.</span></td>
                <td><input type='text' id='itemcode_1' name='itemcode[]'/></td>
                <td><input type='text' id='productname_1' name='productname[]'/></td>
                <td><input type='text' id='quantity_1' name='quantity[]'/></td>

              </tr>  
            </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: several tutorials available if you just search on google. Start with this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: Can you tell me why are you using arrays for input names?

Comment: @karthik Please avoid tutorial type questions.You should do a google search for CRUD with PHP. And this is elementary stuff and not at all difficult if you do your basic homework. Regarding email sending,start off with PHP Mailer .

Comment: thank for all suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
    session_start();
    //In right side, variables contains Post data from form fields.
    //Posted data are stored in Variables
    $itemCode               =   $_POST['item_code'];
    $productName            =   $_POST['product_name'];
    $quantity               =   $_POST['quantity'];

    mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Could not connect");
    mysql_select_db('your database name') or die('Database not found!');        

    //This query will insert data in your database.         
    $query  =   "INSERT INTO tablename(table_fieldname1, table_fieldname2,  table_fieldname3) VALUES('$itemCode', '$productName', '$quantity')";

    $result  =  mysql_query($query);

    if($result){
    header('location: yourpage.php');
    }else{
    echo "Not Entered successfully";
    }
```